# Image stretching and resizing

Tags: html, .net, image, image-manipulation

I have a picture that I need to resize to a specific dimension and then move one of the corner to a place higher than before so the image is not rectangular anymore but some kind of polygon. Is there a library that could help me with this kind of image manipulation or does someone knows the name of this operation?

This is for a .NET application and there is an option for a six-points area also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Anti-Grain Geometry](http://www.antigrain.com/) is an interesting graphical library.  There is also a .NET wrapper called [CreativeDocs.NET](http://www.creativedocs.net/devs/agg).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [here](http://vckicks.110mb.com/image-distortion.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help for certain but you might want to look at CxImage:

http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm